How to show a conditional CDF of a Rosenblatt transformation is uniform distribution?
I am currently reading about how to check the goodness of fit (GOF) for model built using copula functions. There are several methods that we can use to check the GOF which are through the kendall's concordance measure and Rosenblatt transformation.
I want to use the Rosenblatt transformation because it provides a mechanism to check the GOF through graphical assessment. For example, this link show how we can utilize Rosenblatt transformation.
From the Rosenblatt (1952) paper, this transformation will change a vector of variables as follow:
Let say we have 2 variables $X_1, X_2$, with a Rosenblatt transformation, $R$, we can convert these variables into $Z_1, Z_2$ as such,
$$z_1 = F_{X_1}(x_1),$$
$$z_2 = F_{X_2}(x_2|x_1).$$
where $F_{X_i}(.)$ is the CDF function. In Rosenblatt (1952) paper, he mentioned that $Z_1, Z_2$ are independent and uniformly distributed. It is easy to show $Z_1$ follows a uniform distribution. However, how can we show that $Z_2$ also follows a uniform distribution? Can we follow similar argument as $Z_1$?
Idea to proof: We claim $Z_2 = F_{X_2}(x_2|x_1)$ ~ Uniform. Then, let say $F_{X_2}(x_2|x_1)$ is strictly increasing and continuous, this means $F^{-1}_{X_2}(z_2|x_1)$ exists. The CDF of $Z_2$ can be found as,
$$ F(z_2) = P(Z_2 \le z_2)$$
$$ = P(F_{X_2}(x_2|x_1)\le z_2)$$
because $F_{X_2}(x_2|x_1)$ is strictly increasing,
$$ = P(F^{-1}_{X_2}(F_{X_2}(x_2|x_1) | x_1)\le F^{-1}_{X_2}(z_2|x_1))$$
$$ = P(x_2\le F^{-1}_{X_2}(z_2|x_1)|x_1)$$
$$ = F_{X_2}(F^{-1}_{X_2}(z_2|x_1)|x_1)$$
$$ = z_2 $$
which is a CDF for uniform distribution.
Thank you.

The idea looks good. But the notation of $F_{X_2}$ might be $F_{X_2\mid X_1}$. Starting from the 3rd "=" sign from the last, there might be an extra $\mathbb{E}$. It may help if we can keep capital and lower case letters having consistent meaning, i.e., random vs fixed.
